# Third party library method call not trigger calling respect AOP method

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, telegram-bot

I make my telegram bot using java library TelegramBots, Spring Boot and AspectJ in my application.

I have next class that extend third party library class `TelegramLongPollingBot` with class `TelegramBotPolling`.

```
 @Component
 public class TelegramBotPolling extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    static {
       ApiContextInitializer.init();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerBot(){
       TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
       try {
          telegramBotsApi.registerBot(this);
       } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
          logger.error(e);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {   
       ...
    }   
}
```

This libraries class has abstract method `onUpdateReceived` that I implement in my class `TelegramBotPolling`.

I want to keep track when method `onUpdateReceived` is called and will log this method using Spring AOP:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TelegramBotPollingLogger {

   @Around("execution(* ru.cheb.intercity.bus.telegrambot.TelegramBotPolling.onUpdateReceived(..))")
   public Object onUpdateReceivedMethodLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
   {
        Object returnVal = commonLogHandler.handle(joinPoint);
        return returnVal;
   }
}
```

But AOP method `onUpdateReceivedMethodLogger` doesn't called when `onUpdateReceived` is called. I think I have a problem because `onUpdateReceived` relate with third party library. Because my own class methods work well with AOP.

How can I call AOP method `onUpdateReceivedMethodLogger` when method `onUpdateReceived`is called ?

============================================

Trying to inject `TelegramBotPolling` class in other class:

```
  @Component
 public class TelegramBotPolling extends TelegramLongPollingBot implements  TelegramBotUpdater{
    static {
       ApiContextInitializer.init();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {...}

    @Override  
    public String getBotUsername() {...}

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {   
       ...
    }   
}
```

I define interface `TelegramBotUpdater` for `TelegramBotPolling`

```
  public interface TelegramBotUpdater {

     String getBotToken();

     String getBotUsername();

     void onUpdateReceived(Update update);

 }
```

Other class that inject this interface `TelegramBotUpdater`:

```
@Component
public class BotRegistrator {



   @Autowired
   TelegramBotUpdater telegramBotUpdater;

   public void register(){
      TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
      try {
          telegramBotsApi.registerBot((TelegramBotPolling)telegramBotUpdater);
      } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
          logger.error(e);
      }
   }

}
```

And `Application` class that start spring boot application inject other class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

     @Autowired
     BotRegistrator botRegistrator;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        botRegistrator.register();
   }
}
```

When calling `botRegistrator.register();` I get NPE exception.

Comment: Didn't you mean `telegramBotsApi.registerBot(this)` instead of `telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new TelegramBotPolling())`?

Comment: when your TelegramBotPolling bean instance if constructed, it creates a brand new instance, using `new`, and passes that new instance to the external API. That's really not what you want. Inject your TelegramBotPolling bean in some other bean, and register it to the API from that other bean.

Comment: @crizzis that would still bypass AOT, since you would register the class instance, instead of the AOT proxy wrapping it.

Comment: @crizzis, yes it is. Sorry, I corrected my question.

Comment: @JBNizet, I corrected my answer. Actually it creates instance of **TelegramBotPolling** using this: **telegramBotsApi.registerBot(this);**.

Comment: You have a point cut for the `onUpdateReceived` without any arguments, that will obviously not match. Use `onUpdateReceived(..)` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I changed **onUpdateReceived** to **onUpdateReceived(..)**. But unfortunately it doesn't help me (I also corrected my questions source code).

Comment: How is this method getting called? As it is an `abstract` method you implemented I guess it is an internal method call and Spring AOP will not help you with that.

Comment: @M.Deinum, method `onUpdateReceived` call asynchronously by third party library and I don't call it explicitly.

Comment: @foxis as I said, this would still bypass AOT, since AOT is proxy-based. Spring creates a proxy that delegates to your actual bean instane and injects that proxy in other beans. If you pass `this` to the API, you pass the class instance, not the proxy created by Spring and wrapping the class instance. Do as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: @JBNizet, I try to do as your recomended (inject `TelegramBotPolling` in other class) but after that I get error. Please check my question source code I have added my changes there.

Comment: Again, you're creating a spring bean using `new`. You need to get the bean from the context in order to have it injected by Spring. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-client. Regarding your error, either define an interface for your TelegramBotPolling, containing all the methods supposed to be callable for that bean, and inject that interface, or use CGLib as explained in the error message.

Comment: @JBNizet, I change my code and add another interface and also inject intermediate class (`BotRegistrator `) in `Application ` class at this time I get **nullPointerException** in row `botRegistrator.register();` of this class.